# Как сделать сохранение кастомных полей в личном кабинете WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

С помощью плагина Advanced Custom Fields создал небольшую анкету и поместил ее в личном кабинете WooCommerce, на странице эндпоинта my-account. За эту страницу отвечает файл dashboard.php.

Но мне нужно, чтобы все данные при заполнении этой анкеты сохранялись. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Может быть, можно переделать кнопку со страницы эндпоинта edit-account?

```
<p class="adress-button">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
    <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во время сохранения данных в личном кабинете срабатывает действие `woocommerce_save_account_details`. Вот рабочий код из одного моего проекта:

```
/**
 * Action to save additional user account details.
 */
function woocommerce_save_account_details_action() {
    $user_id = wp_get_current_user()->ID;
    if ( 0 !== $user_id ) {
        $account_company = ! empty( $_POST['account_company'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['account_company'] ) : '';
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'company', $account_company );

        $account_phone = ! empty( $_POST['account_phone'] ) ? wc_clean( $_POST['account_phone'] ) : '';
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $account_phone );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'woocommerce_save_account_details_action' );
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, этот код работает только на странице эндпоинта edit-account? А как быть с другими страницами?

Comment: У вас в вопросе ни слова про другие эндпойнты.

Comment: У меня в вопросе речь про страницу эндпоинта my-account, за которую отвечает файл dashboard. На этой странице, я разместил анкету, созданную в ACF. Теперь мне нужно разместить кнопку для сохранения результатов заполнения анкеты.

Comment: Нет такого эндпойнта my-account - см.код http://take.ms/0Pye7 Есть edit-account, куда вы и поместили свои поля. При сохранении данных в этом эндпойнте срабатывает хук, указанный в моём ответе. Вы получите свои поля в $_POST (если, конечно, поместили их внутрь формы).

Comment: Тогда поясню. В ACF я указал местом размещения анкеты Account Dashboard (это файл dashboard.php). На странице эндпоинта edit-account я ничего не размещал и анкеты там нет. Поэтому я и прошу помощь с кнопкой сохранения, потому что мне нужна анкета именно на Account Dashboard.

Comment: Можете подсказать по кнопке сохранения именно для Account Dashboard?

Comment: Я вам дал абсолютно рабочий ответ, который сохраняет по кнопке, указанной вами в вопросе. Если вам нужно со вкладки dashboard сохранять, делайте там форму свою, в ней поля ACF и кнопку submit. Какеи проблемы-то? Банальная форма php.